# How to find out PySpark version used in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue + PySpark connecting to Oracle in AWS.  How do I find out which version of PySpark is being used?

Comment: Have you tried printing spark.version and then find related python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS glue supports python v2.7 only